# Watch variable value change in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input type text and i need to watch the variable bound to that input for changes.

I tried with Observables but it doesn't trigger the change event.

Can someone give me an example or some documentation?

Comment: Please improve your question. It's quite unclear what the problem is. For example add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someField">
```

or

```
<input (change)="someMethod($event.target.value)
```